# Revolution Slider delayed navigation area

Tags: wordpress

I have a revolution slider that has some animation.  I would like for the header section (logo and menu created in WordPress) to fade in after 10 seconds.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Answer (score 0):

Go to wordpress admin panel , slider setting them Global Setting and set Default Slide duration to 10000.

[image]